# Calling a curried function that uses an implicit

Tags: scala, implicit

Given the function

```
def func(implicit x: Foo, y: Bar): (ThingA => ThingB) = ???`
```

I can't figure out how to call it on one line. Obviously this works by storing the returned function in a val:

```
val f = func // Foo and Bar are implicitly applied
f(ThingA)
```

but how to do it without the assignment to val? `func(ThingA)` naturally complains that `func` has been called with too few arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest is probably to explicitly call `apply`:

```
func.apply(ThingA)
```